# EF Core queries not working correctly in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ef-core-2.2

I see that Azure SQL Database is using version 12.x, which is SQL 2014. Some of my LINQ queries that works in dev boxes Visual studio 2019 (which uses SQL 2016 for SQL Express) does not work correctly after deploying to Azure SQL Database. No errors but returns no result where it is supposed to return rows.

Any option to use later version of SQL in Azure SQL database? Otherwise I have to go back to deploy SQL Server in Azure instead.

I use CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync to dynamically compile part of the predicate. I'm using ASP.Net Core, EF Core 2.2.4.

Comment: Post your code. If you get no results it means nothing matched the query criteria. If Azure SQL had a problem with SQL queries you can be sure it would be global news

Comment: `I use CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync to dynamically compile part of the predicate.` You can't compile SQL queries on the client. SQL queries are compiled by the *database server* and the outcome is an execution plan, not executable code. I suspect the *real* problem is that some part of the query can't be translated into SQL and gets evaluated locally using LINQ to Objects.

Comment: Yes, still result has to be same though it is sub optimal to run on client. I ended up pulling the dynamic part as last condition in the predicate and it worked as expected. Issue is not with SQL but with the combination of static and dynamic parts in predicate of LINQ query.

Comment: The major version number in sql azure is hard coded.  It is actually closest to sql 2019 presently.  The compatibility level is the main way to tell the semantic “version” for sql azure.

Comment: Did you performed an assessment of your database prior to deploying to Azure SQL Database? This way you know if your database has any incompatibilities with Azure SQL Database that you need to deal with.